# Thymeleaf path variable is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Something is keeping me from setting a path variable with Thymeleaf and HTML in an HTML Form.
I want to simply enter 33 into a form and get localhost:8080/blog/33  for a url, but I can only get a query string or malformed brackets and etc.

some example attempts and results:
th:action="@{/blog/{id}(id = ${id})}"
localhost:8080/blog/?id=33

th:action="@{/blog/+ ${id}}"
localhost:8080/blog/+%20$%7Bid%7D?id=33

what I want is:
localhost:8080/blog/33

the whole code for this form is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Form Submission</title>
        <style>
            button{
                margin-top:20px;
                width: 250px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Delete Entry</h2>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/blog/{id}(id = ${id})}" th:object="${blog}" method="get" >  
            <fieldset>
                <p>Delete ID: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" required /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = '/'">Menu</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about using standard concatenation, with no use of the special URL `@{...}` syntax: `th:action="'/blog/' + ${id}"`. You don't explicitly need the host and port parts (it's all happening in-app - I assume). CAVEAT - I use Thymeleaf, but not Spring - so that may make a difference.

Comment: Just to add to my first comment - your first example works fine for me, for some reason.  So, pasting directly from my code, `th:action="@{/blog/{id}(id = ${id})}"` gives me the following: `http://localhost:7000/blog/33`. Odd.

Comment: I pasted your first example in just now th:action="'/blog/' + ${id}" and the result was localhost:8080/blog/null?id=33.  I've tried everything with this!

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is correct: `@{/blog/{id}(id = ${id})}`.

The reason you are getting `localhost:8080/blog/?id=33` is probably because `${id}` is empty when the form is created, and when you click the submit button, it is adding `?id=33` to the url (because the method is `get` and you have an input with the same `name="id"`: `<input type="text" th:field="*{id}" required />`.

There is no html/thymeleaf way (without javascript) to get a form field into the path part of a URL (if that is what you're expecting).  You'll have to use a javascript library if you want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I had a misunderstanding in how this should work.
So for everyone who is still struggling with this, here an other description. Maybe it helps.

What I like to see in the browser is:

```
data-url="jobendpoint/deletestatistics/16/57?jobStatisticsId=3"
```

Pre-sets in Spring model:
`jobid=16`,
`ts.id=57`,
`js.id=3`

So what I did was:

```
th:data-url="@{jobendpoint/deletestatistics/{jobid}/{ts.id}(jobStatisticsId = ${js.id})}"
```

which leads to the following output in the browser (wrong):

```
data-url="jobendpoint/deletestatistics/{jobid}/{ts.id}?jobStatisticsId=3"
```

but if I did the following:

```
th:data-url="|jobendpoint/deletestatistics/${jobid}/${ts.id}/${js.id}|"
```

that leads to this output in the browser (working, but not like it should be):

```
data-url="jobendpoint/deletestatistics/16/57/3"
```

Now I could be sure the values where set correctly in the backend. But why they hell they are not printed out correctly?

**the right way to do the this is:**

```
th:data-url="@{jobendpoint/deletestatistics/{jobid}/{ts.id}(jobid=${jobid}, ts.id=${ts.id}, jobStatisticsId = ${js.id})}"
```

or to make it more obvious:

```
th:data-url="@{jobendpoint/deletestatistics/{a}/{b}(a=${jobid}, b=${ts.id}, jobStatisticsId = ${js.id})}"
```

So the point is that the path variables in the first part of this expression
`@{jobendpoint/deletestatistics/{jobid}/{ts.id}...` are some local variables for thymeleaf and of course local variables have to be set/initialize. This happens in the bracket part
`(jobid=${jobid}**, ...)`.

The Spring-Boot Model-Variables are only visible in the bracket part, so I had to "copy/reinitialize" them to make them available in the expression itself as well.

Hop this will help others...